# How would you automate the login process in this site?

Tags: python

Alright, so, I'm doing a little script that downloads X number of wallpapers of this website.

www.wallbase.cc

I can already download the way I want but I want to login with my username and password from a Python Script, I've kinda find out how to do it in "plain" websites where the login form is visible from the url but in this on I have to call a javascript function to show the webform to login and sincerely I have no idea how to login neither open the webform.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would first check if this isn't a voliation of their T&C, and then proceed with [`selenium`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: It isn't a violation of the T&C, I've already checked that, also it's just for personal use (My dad wants a big collection of wallpapers but downloads them by hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a POST method to send your credentials.

LiveHTTPHeaders firefox module is very useful to trace HTTP requests :

```
http://wallbase.cc/user/login

POST /user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: wallbase.cc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://wallbase.cc/home
Cookie: xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 74
usrname=d&pass=d&nopass_email=Type+in+your+e-mail+and+press+enter&nopass=0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 05:05:21 GMT
Server: lighttpd
```

The important part is

```
usrname=<YOUR USER NAME>&pass=<PASSWORD>&nopass_email=Type+in+your+e-mail+and+press+enter&nopass=0
```

that's the data you need to send via POST. You will find plenty of POST in python in a search on the SO site.

I recommend you to use `mechanize` module to do that.

Comment: I've got this:

from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open('http://www.wallbase.cc/user/login_form')
br['usrname'] = 'myUserName'
submit_response = br.submit(name='Preview', label='Preview')
br.back()
br['pass'] = 'myPassWord'
submit_response = br.submit(name='Create', label='Create New Page')

but It doesn't seem to work, can you help me please?

Comment: Try that -> http://pastie.org/5058111 & read mechanize doc.

Comment: That didn't work at first but gave me an idea, here's the solution:
http://pastie.org/5059705

Thanks a lot!